# Does a switch and patch panel need a cabinet in a private home setup?

Tags: home-networking

Usually one installs switches and patch panels in a suitable cabinet. Is this necessary for the network installation of a private home?

In my case I have 19 CAT 7 cables which end in a room of my basement (new house) which I want to connect to a patch panel and a switch using either 19 or 10 inch devices.

To save space I am considering installing it without a cabinet directly on the wall like this:

[image]

or using a small open rack like this:

[image]

So why is a cabinet important and "how necessary" is it for a small private home network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding any applicable local building codes, a cabinet is not necessary in a private dwelling.

Networking cabinets are deployed to provide things like access and climate control. They keep the network equipment and wiring termination points away from curious (or careless) hands. Most include some sort of cable management system. They usually have independent electrical circuits feeding them and in many cases have dedicated earth grounds.

In a home environment most of these features are nice to have, but as long as you don't expect anyone to start pulling on the cables or unplug things, you aren't required to have a dedicated network cabinet.

For what it's worth, network technicians often find network equipment installed in locations that **should** have a cabinet or closet, but for whatever reason don't...and usually the network is still intact. *Usually...*

Comment: Thanks. What's about dust protection. Is this a critical point?

Comment: @student - What?  Unless you are purposefully breading, dust bunnies inside the equipment, the equipment should be fine.  Just keep the surrounding area clean

Comment: @student  Cabinets/Racks are not designed to stop dust.  They are designed to allow air to flow through them.

Answer (score -1):

No it makes ZERO difference.  I have mine in a cabinet when people see it it looks just like a kitchen cabinet.  Only if they open it can you see the messy wires.   Some people get very anal about it and use pink blue wires then post it on the internet likes its some kind of fashion show.